# SetWindowLong Clickable Form Elements

Tags: c#, setwindowlong

I use `SetWindowLong` to make my Form click through for an overlay. I want to create Buttons and some Elements which are clickable but the Form should be still invisible because it's an overlay.

My OnLoad Function:

```
this.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Wheat;
this.TopMost = true;
//this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);

GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
this.Size = new Size(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
this.Top = rect.top;
this.Left = rect.left;
```

Some other sections:

```
public struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}
```

And

```
RECT rect;
public const string WINDOW_NAME = "WINDOWNAME_WHATEVER";
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WINDOW_NAME);
```

What exact happening to my Buttons and how can I get this working?

Comment: What's the back color of your buttons? Are they visible, but not clickable?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield yes thats correct i can see them but when i want to click them i click trough the form and click on the stuff in the Background of the form

Comment: What additional window styles are you setting (I'm not looking up those constants).

Comment: @MarkBenningfield No one else than u can see in my OnLoad Function. Running on Win 10 64x System